# (Debugging) Langchain tools

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

I have a local LLM that I'm running with langchain with custom tools. For some reason, my model doesn't want to use those custom tools. I've been searching the (langchain repo)[https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain] trying to figure out where the agent during the agent loop actually calls the tools that it has access to. The closest I've found was this in building a (ReAct agent)[https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/langchain/langchain/agents/react/agent.py#L105] but still even from this it's unclear to me where the model is triggering the tools, waiting for their response, and then piping those inputs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if this is an obvious question.

-bitwise

I tried setting up a basic LLM model using Llama.cpp with an LLMChain inside of an agent

```
llm = LlamaCpp(model_path="./mistral_7b_instruct/mistral-7b-instruct-v0.1.Q4_K_M.gguf", verbose=True)


template = """
You are a helpful chat agent that is fun and quirky.

Here are your tools to help you
{tools}

Here's the input from the user {input}

{agent_scratchpad}

"""
@tool
def confetti(string: str) -> str:
   """Adds a random word to the string"""
   return "confetti + string"


agent = create_react_agent(
    tools=[confetti],
    llm=llm,
    prompt=PromptTemplate.from_template(template),
)
agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)
agent_executor.invoke(input="Could you add confetti to "My (blank) seahorse?")
```

Note that the template is a rough example.